# determining view boundaries based on z position when using a perspective projection

Tags: camera, perspective, three.js

I'm using three.js to make an animation of a box moving around the screen in 3 dimensions.

It is moving pseudo-randomly, according to a noise function. So, I want to place an invisible wall just outside of view, so the box tends to stay in the screen.

I have accomplished this. However, it only works correctly when the box's z coordinate is 0.

I need a function that calculates the boundaries based on the z coordinate of the box. Right now, if z is negative (farther away) the boundary is too small and if z is positive the boundary gets too big.

I am not sure how to go about this. This is how I am creating the camera, I am new to three.js and this part I just copied from a tutorial:

```
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 1, 10000);
camera.position.z=1000;
```

This is the function signature from the docs:

**PerspectiveCamera( fov, aspect, near, far )**

- fov: Camera frustum vertical field of view.
- aspect: Camera frustum aspect ratio.
- near: Camera frustum near plane.
- far: Camera frustum far plane.

I'm not really sure what FOV does but I think it may be the key here....
If FOV allows me to get a relevant angle than I can probably use basic trig to find my offset value.

Comment: you want to calculate the camera frustum boundarys?

Comment: does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12018710/calculate-near-far-plane-vertices-using-three-frustum

Comment: @LukeP, did any of the answers help you with your problem? I need to award the bounty.

Comment: Great, glad you could find your answer here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

FOV is field of view. Everyone likes to say that there is no camera in OpenGL, but to me that's a silly notion to hold on to even if it might be technically true.  When you use the perspectiveCamera function you are essentially creating a camera.  So think of the FOV as the type of lens.  Is it a wide angle lens or more of a zoom lens?

The FOV is given as an angle.  If it's a smaller number things that are farther away will appear larger.  If it's a larger number things that are farther away will appear smaller.  This is exactly like a real lens.  In a way, smaller FOV's sort of *compress* the distance.

The way a lens works is that the visible plane at any farther distance is bigger than the visible plane at a shorter distance.  Looking through a lens you can see the width of an entire city in the distance but only the width of a park bench in the foreground. The value you're trying to fix is this: What is the size of the visible X at a given Z.  Then the Y height can be calculated using aspect ratio math.

I don't know three.js or even java. But that's not important because this is a pure math problem that you can translate into any programming language.  I have a couple of links here.

First is when I tried to work this out originally.  A question (and answer) that I wrote here on SE.  It's fairly generic to which library you're using.  It's mostly just the matrix math:  [In 3D camera math, calculate what Z depth is pixel unity for a given FOV](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/75061/in-3d-camera-math-calculate-what-z-depth-is-pixel-unity-for-a-given-fov)

Second is a video I did on how to do it in Unity3D.  That one shows the code and an example of altering the FOV and seeing an object slide to stay at a specific x/y size.  It's using the same type of math.  You can find it on my blog here: http://gameweasel.com/pixel-perfect-sprites-in-unity3d/

Last I'll give you the actual formula to do what you're wanting. The size of the frustum at any distance can be easily calculated:

```
frustumHeight = 2.0 * distance * tan(fov * 0.5 * (pi/180));
```

That calculates the total hight of the frustum at any `distance` from the camera.  If the center of your screen is `0,0` then the Y bounds of your frustum are (+ and -) 1/2 that amount.  So just remove the `2.0 *` part of the formula and then that will be the Y bounds in both the positive and negative directions.

That `distance` value in my formula might just be the z coordinate if your camera is at zero.  Where your camera is in 3d space is determined by your View Matrix or your lookAt matrix.  If it's not at 0 it's going to be an offset amount from your camera, or the distance from the camera.  It's obviously in the bounds between your `near` and `far` values that you used.

Then to get the X bounds you'll take your `aspect` and the height result of the above formula and do:

```
frustumWidth = frustumHeight * aspect;
```

That will give you either the total width if you included the `2.0 *` or the X bounds if you didn't.

Comment: The link to the gameweasel page is broken, perhaps you could quote it here?

Comment: Thanks for letting me know.  I'm not sure why that is.  Looking in to it.

Comment: Link is fixed. It's working now. Wordpress theme updated and messed up my permalinks.